# Steady state solution to density matrix

Tags: hamiltonian, density-operator, steady-state

A density matrix follows the dynamics

$$
\dot{\rho} = \mathcal{L}\rho, 
$$

where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Liouvillian super-operator. If put in Lindblad form, it can be written as
$$
\mathcal{L}\rho = -i[H,\rho] + A\rho A^\dagger - \frac{1}{2}\{A^\dagger A,\rho\}.
$$
The steady-state of the system can be found by solving $\dot{\rho} = \mathcal{L}\rho = 0$. Under which circumstances is the solution unique? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This might help: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06279.pdf.

Comment: @Tim I'll check it